# parsing JSON data in C# from Twitter Streaming API

Tags: c#, twitter, streaming

I'm trying to parse the tweets returning from twitter's stream, it seems everybody instructs me to use JSON.Net, however, I can't get it to work with .net 3.5

Anybody have any sample code without using .net 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the correct [download](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/50552).